# What information can bundling give me about a bug?

Tags: magento2.4.3, jsbundling

I have an issue (caused by one of my modules) that only appears when in production mode, when the javascript files have been bundled. I disabled bundling and the issue does not persist in production mode and it never showed up in developer mode to begin with.

Does this give me any indication on what exactly might be causing the issue? Does this necessarily mean that there is a conflict between scripts manipulating the same component or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this things.

1. Try to disable third party extension one by one and check does that issues not occures.
2. So in this way you will get information is that from third party extension or not and then try to resolve that one by checking that extension js files.